# Windows To Go not booting from NVMe Enclosure on some computers

Tags: uefi, windows-to-go

I managed to install Windows (10) To Go UEFI to an NVMe SSD enclosed in a USB 3.2 case through Rufus. I created the bootable disk on a laptop (let's call it PC1). The first time I booted the WTG, I booted it on another laptop (PC2) and it booted fine, it did some initialization of the installation and some updates. I used it for a few hours (including some turn on and power off) and did its job fine. However, after some time, I stopped being able to boot on it from PC2, (it didn't appear on the UEFI menu). Generally it didn't appear as a bootable device. I then tried to boot in on PC1 and it booted fine. Now I cannot boot it on PC2 and I can only boot it on PC1. Any solutions or thoughts are welcome. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This will be one of the many reasons Microsoft gave up on it entirely & quietly retired it more than two years ago. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview

Comment: If you want a portable OS, look at other systems, such as Linux. It is simple to create a bootable external drive with *persistence*, to retain data and OS changes. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ Your choice of SSD is much better than flash, however, because flash memory is slow, and such a PC would be lethargic.